# Spring Security LDAP and Database

Tags: spring-security-ldap

I need help/example on how to implement both LDAP (Active Directory) and Database authentication for spring security .

I started from gs-spring-security-3.2-master on github , and want to add LDAP to it .

BR

Comment: If you have no clue where to start I would suggest to search for previous spring ldap. There are already some topics with code examples in the questions.

Comment: @Nils Thanks , i already did good progress couldn't put all in comment so i put them in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677279/spring-ldap-active-directory-with-sql)